# How to save (temporarily) form data?

Tags: django

There are, say, 10 fields on page1 and hyperlink to page2. Also there is hyperlink on page2 to page1. I fill 5 fields and click on the hyperlink. Then I click on the hyperlink on page2 and return to page1. Is it possible to save filled fields and how?
Additional question: what if page2 modifies fields of page1. For example, creates new choice in multichoice field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save filled fields using cookies via javascript after clicking on the link and before going to another page. For example it's possible to use this jQuery plugin [jQuery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). As documentations says:

```
A simple, lightweight jQuery plugin for reading, writing and deleting cookies.

Create session cookie:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:    
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire page:    
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

Read cookie:    
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null

Delete cookie by passing null as value:    
$.cookie('the_cookie', null);

Note: when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie.
```

Answer (score 2):

Django has implemented solution which allow to split forms on multiple web pages. It is called form wizard. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) for the tutorial.

EDIT 1#

Check this questions up: [Django Passing data between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763115/passing-data-between-views), [How do you pass or share variables between django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570131/how-do-you-pass-or-share-variables-between-django-views)

Comment: I don't need to split form. The problem is in doing action while clicking on link. Is it possible only with JavaScript or Django have special capabilities?

Comment: There are already some answers for your question on stackoverflow.

Comment: The main problem not in saving data, but in doing it while clicking on the link. This is impossible without JavaScript, as I can understand. Thanks, anyway.