# Django - get an object back from template form to view (from a search result)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django app, the user is presented a simple form, on validation the view searches the data (some web scraping) and returns a template in the context of which we added a list of the results, we present them to the user and he/she chooses one and (this is my problem) **I want to get that choice back to another view** (now we want to add the selected object to the database).

I identified my problem, but I really think I'm missing something and not using Django the right way. For now this is how I display the data and put it back in a form: (jade template. Of course I do this with many more attributes so the template is quite big and I have to add an hidden input for each value I want back)

```
for b in result_list
      h4
        for aut in b.authors
          div {{ aut }}   

      form(action='/add/', method='post') {% csrf_token %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        input(type='hidden', value="{{ b.authors }}", name='authors')
```

**edit2**: there is one button per book. I am just trying to return one book.

It works fine when authors has a single element, but *with more than once the template doesn't return a valid json*. I could give you the structure but I tend to think this is not the point.

What am I missing ? How to display search results and get the selected one to another view ?

Do I miss something about forms ? Shall I use a session variable, a context processor with middleware ? I guess the hidden input is wrong: how can I do differently ?

many thanks

---

***edit:*** below I show where my problem is. However, maybe I shouldn't fix that problem but use Django the right way instead.

1- my 1st view renders a template and feeds it with the search results:

```
    return render(request, "search/search_result.jade", {
        "return_list": book_list,
        })
```

`book_list` is a list of dicts where `authors` is a list of unicode str:

```
retlist[0]["authors"]
>>> [u'Ayroles, Alain']
```

2- my template is above. It displays a form and a hidden input. The goal is to send back a book: a dictionnary with the title, the editor… and a list of authors.

3- now the users clicks "Add this book", we are in the "add" view. Let's inspect the authors:

```
req = request.POST.copy()
authors = req["authors"]
>>> u"[u'Ayroles']"  # note the u after the [
# this is not a valid json, I can't get a list out of it
import json
json.loads(req["authors"])
>>> *** ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

So I passed a list from the first view to the template, I parsed it and displayed it, but the template doesn't return a valid list/json to the second view in the POST parameters and I can't extract my authors. I don't know what to think:

- else what I want to do is fine and I just have to better handle my data structure
- else I shouldn't be doing like that and use more of Django: use more forms ? sessions ?

Comment: can you provide more details? I still can't get what is the problem. E.g. - I have page, there is a multiple select, form contains ids in -format-, I would like to pass the selected object ids to a form handler, which should do -blablablah-, it doesn't work right, instead of -what-expected- I get -wrong-result-. Also, template(?) (pseudo?)code looks strange

Comment: Hi, maybe this is what makes it more difficult: there is no object id, because I don't get my search results from the database. (the template is a jade template, which compiles to html: http://jade-lang.com/reference/ the indentation is important, like in python). A derived question: do you think it is good practice to write ±10 hidden inputs in the templates in order to get back the values ?

Comment: well, you will have to identify these entities somehow anyway (URL, maybe). Yes, having multiple hidden input is totally ok. Should user be able to select multiple items? How do you want user to select author(s) (e.g. by ticking box(es), dropdown list, clicking a particular one)?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to show it, there's a 'Add this book' button. Thanks for reassuring me about the hidden inputs :p I'll add more details.

Comment: @Marat I gave more details. Don't you think there is a better way of doing this ?

Comment: you're welcome :) either I didn't get your concern or it's just my terrible English. But back to the business, as far as I understand, you want one button for each book, and this button submits form (again, only one book per submit). Is having one form per book would be an option?

Comment: ok, that "u" thing in JSON, it looks like a bug in template rendering. Can you check the page source for how it looks in HTML?

Comment: @Marat: indeed, there's one button for each book and one book per submit. You ask if one form per book would be an option: and I ask you back: your explanation as to "why and how using a form per book" would be a nice answer :) I started web dev with AngularJS, so I'm used to doing a lot in the template. But the logic seems to be different with Django forms. Now that I asked it, forms look to be a better way. Would you discuss that a bit ? thanks (ps: and I'm not a native english speaker too !)

Comment: about the u in the json: it comes from my step n°1. The `book_list[0]["authors"]` has this 'u', but it is a valid python list with a unicode string. So maybe I could encode them to something else before passing the list to the template, but that sounds terribly wrong. Or it is a bug in the template rendering.

Comment: Note: the full code is on gitlab, but I don't think I should post a personal link on SO and that may not necessarily help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it: we can easily share data between views using the `session`.

The session is activated in the default Django install. We just have to choose a session engine: in a temporary file, in memory,…

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
```

Now in my `search/` url I can add a variable in `request.session`, a dictionnary-like object:

```
search_results = compute_and_get_data()
request = search_results()
```

I feed my template with the `search_results` list. In my template, I iterate on it and I use a **single** hidden input field to return the counter of the for loop.

```
for b in search_results
  table
    tr
      td
        h4 {{b.authors}}


  form(action='/add/', method='post') {% csrf_token %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    input(type='hidden', value="{{ forloop.counter0 }}", name='forloop_counter0')
    input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='add book', title="add that book to my collection")
```

On submit, we enter the `add/` view. Here I can get the book the user selected:

```
forloop_counter0 = int(request.POST["forloop_counter0"])
book = request.session["search_result"][forloop_counter0]
```

Now my `book` is a dictionnary with a lot of information. I didn't have to handle json formatting and the like.

This question helped me:

- [Django Passing data between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763115/django-passing-data-between-views)
- [How do you pass or share variables between django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570131/how-do-you-pass-or-share-variables-between-django-views)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see it. It is not really an answer, but it's already too much code to put into comments

Template:

```
for b in result_list
  h4
    for aut in b.authors
      div {{ aut }}   
      form(action='/add/', method='post')
          {% csrf_token %}
          input(type='hidden', value="{{ b.authors }}", name='authors')
          input(type='submit', value="Add book")
```

View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    authors = request.POST.get['authors']
    #do something with authors, e.g. create a JSON string:
    authors_JSON = json.dumps(authors)
```

Same logic, using Django forms:

View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    book = BookForm(request.POST)
    #do something with authors, e.g. create a JSON string:
    authors_JSON = json.dumps(book.authors)
```

Forms.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    authors = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    #etc, possibly including custom __init__ logic
```

That 'u' thing, it happens because you do json.loads() on an object. If you want to serialize, it should be json.dumps(), otherwise array converted to string and then treated as JSON, that is why Python unicode mark got there (i.e. not a template bug)

Comment: Thanks. It isn't very clear in my head how to manage a list of authors but I'll see how it goes with forms (will mark as accepted in a few days). However I didn't `loads` on an object but on a string (which is the representation of the object). You say I should serialize the list of authors before putting it in the form and giving it to the template ? Ok then, that makes sense.

Comment: in case you have multiple inputs with name=authors, response.POST['authors'] is a list, otherwise it's a string. In any case I don't see why you need to serialize it before passing to template, I assumed it was part of your application logic

Comment: mmmh I'm currently reading about class based views and that may be the way to go. I would declare the search results as a class attribute so that they are visible from my 2 views (methods of the class). Thus in my template I wouldn't have to return every field of the book but just a unique id. I won't bother anymore about the format the authors' list is returned in. Hopefully that's how it works. What's your opinion on that ? Thanks again :)

Comment: I don't see the full picture, but if it works for you then go for it. Class based views generally lead to simpler code and speedup development. You can also try "fat" models, in your case it can also be useful