# django how to use a variable globally

Tags: python, django

I have a variable in one of my view

```
def ViewName(request):
      simple_variable = request.session['value']
```

in the same views.py file,i have another view

```
def AnotherViewName(request):
    --------------------
    --------------------
```

now i want to use the variable `simple_variable` in my `AnotherViewName` view ,i have tried

```
def AnotherViewName(request):
     global simple_variable
```

but,its not worked,now my question is,how can i use  a variable from one view to another view in Django or how can i use a variable globally?

**in mention** the `simple_variable` is storing value from the `session` and initially i have to call it within my above given `ViewName` view.

i am using django 1.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do this way:

```
simple_variable = initial_value 

def ViewName(request):
    global simple_variable
    simple_variable = value
    ...

def AnotherViewName(request):
    global simple_variable
```

Comment: in mention,there is no initial for my `simple_variable`,i have to store value in this variable from a session within my `ViewName` in this way def ViewName(request): simple_variable = request.session['value']

Comment: @Rego you can set simple_variable = None. And update it in your view function.

Comment: Isn't this going to be problematic in a multithreaded/processed environment?

Comment: Add session in middleware , it works as a global varibale across the project

Answer (score 5):

There is no state shared between views as they probably runs in another thread. So if you want to share data between views you have to use a database, files, message-queues or sessions.

Here is another stackoverflow about this.
[How do you pass or share variables between django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570131/how-do-you-pass-or-share-variables-between-django-views)

**Update after rego edited the question:**

Can't you do it like this?

```
def ViewName(request):
     simple_variable = request.session['value']

def AnotherViewName(request):
     simple_variable = request.session['value']
```

Comment: i can't do this,because i have to make sure that the value i am passing with variable must be permanent,as we know that anything storing in `session` is temporary.So i can't.

Comment: in fact i am intended to use this variable in one of my `download` view,now as we know that user can any time download a content,he/she is not bounded to do so within a session.

Comment: I understand but global variables is not something you usually should be using. I think we need more info about what your goal is to make a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use a [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views).

```
def ViewName(request):
      #retrieve your value
      if 'value' in request.session:
          simple_variable = request.session['value']

def AnotherViewName(request):
    #set your varaible
    request.session['value'] = simple_variable
```