# django using a variable in any templates

Tags: django

for example: in the templates you will use your **site name** a lot of times.
 in the future if you want to change your website name you must edit all templates files you wrote your site name in them
is there a way to define a variable  and use that variable in all templates without using context in views

I tried to define and use settings.py properties with this code but doesn't work

```
{{SITE_NAME}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django how to use a variable globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792142/django-how-to-use-a-variable-globally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), here is an example for your use case:

[How can I get the domain name of my site within a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451138/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-of-my-site-within-a-django-template/8981537#8981537)

Answer (score 0):

You need a context processor:
https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangocontextprocessors.html